# Does anyone have a working class for stageVideo that works on mobile application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

Does anyone know a good helper class for stageVideo with as3 that works well on tablets or a tutorial? I'm trying to find something to help me get started so i don't have to start from scratch. 
Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using StageVideo on mobile is not really something that requires a class or SDK. It's pretty much the same as using the normal video API's

Check out this link:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html

And make sure you're publishing with AIR 3.2

Comment: The link you provided does not work with CS6. the onAddedToStage event never fires and the stage references are all null since you're in a class. much recoding to do here. I also need a simple project for CS6 that demonstrates StageVideo.